# Docker not running/starting in MacOS mojave and fails with supervisor has failed message

Tags: docker

I successfully installed Docker.dmg file from docker hub. But when I launch docker in my mac it gives me this popup and docker doesn't startup.

[image]

I tried clicking Reset Docker button and also Diagnose & Feedback, still nothing. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you install docker-machine and can you run docker from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I have access to both docker-machine and docker in cmd line.